# Launch an application by a double click

Tags: ubuntu, application, icons, launcher

I installed `code blocks` from binary to `/opt/cb`
I wonder how to create a link 
 which I can click and launch the application.

I can launch it by

```
$ /opt/cb/bin/codeblocks
```

However, the file `/opt/cb/bin/codeblocks` itself, does not allow me to launch by a click.

I chose `Allow executing file as program` but it did not work.

How can I make it?

Comment: You should make an icon you can click on to start the application. Here are instructions for GNome: https://developer.gnome.org/integration-guide/stable/desktop-files.html.en You didn't write what environment (desktop) you are using. Find information for your desktop environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a .desktop file in `~/.local/share/applications/` or `/usr/share/applications/` which will contain folowing lines.

Example:

`nano ~/.local/share/applications/codeblocks.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Code::Blocks
Type=Application
Comment=The open source, cross platform, free C, C++ and Fortran IDE
Exec=/opt/cb/bin/codeblocks
Icon=codeblocks
Categories=Development;IDE;
```

Then you can find it between your other program launchers in menu.

Comment: Thank you but I wonder what difference is between packages, I can run some without using a desktop file but otheres do not, like 'codeblocks'

Comment: @kensuke1984 If program has executables in $PATH, you can launch them by their name. So if you want same behaviour with codeblocks, you can do for example `ln -s /opt/cb/bin/codeblocks ~/.local/bin/codeblocks`